# Date picker inside table cell missing minutes on iPad

Tags: ios, uidatepicker

I have a date picker (time mode) showing hour, minutes and am/pm on iPhone, but when running on iPad, it's only showing hour and am/pm.

The date picker is the only object in the table cell, and has autolayout of center horizontally in content view.

Did anyone have such a problem, and any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Removing the date picker and re-adding it resolved the issue.